# Integral $\int \frac{\tan^4 \theta \,d \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evaluate this indefinite integral $$\int \frac{\tan^4 \theta\, d \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}$$
I tried it as follows $$I=\int\frac{(\sec^2 \theta-1)\tan^2 \theta\, d \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}=\int\frac{\sec^2 \theta \tan^2 \theta\, d \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}-\int\frac{\tan^2 \theta \,d \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}$$
First part of integration can be easily solved by substitution but how to solve the second part? Help to solve it by other method if you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the substitution  $u=\tan\theta$, $\;\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu u=(1+u^2)\mkern1.5mu\mathrm d\mkern1mu\theta$. You'll get the integral of the rational function:
$$\int\frac{u^4}{1-u^4}\,=\int\frac{u^4}{(1-u)(1+u)(1+u^2)}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u$$
Then, decomposition into partial fractions and back to $\theta$.

Comment: @Harish Chandra Rajpoot: Thank you for the correction of the lapsus.

Comment: But $du = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$...

Comment: yes you are right. It needs re-editing!

Comment: @Harish Chandra Rajpoot: finally there was no error in my initial post. I was suggested a correction that I accepted. Only some details were missing.

Comment: Yes, you are. Sorry I could not point out earlier, you are absolutely right. I re-edited it

Comment: Very good!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano! Note I just applied Bioche's rules for this substitution

Comment: @Bernard The briosche :-) rule is it $u=\tan\theta$? :-)

Comment: Not exactly: it says to determine whether the differential form $f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is invariant under the substitution $x\to -x$, $x\to\pi -x$ and $x\to\pi +x$. If it is the case for one of them, you can use as a new variable the function which is invariant by the same substitution to obtain the integral of a rational function, i.e. set $u=\cos x$, $u=\sin x$ or $u=\tan x$ respectively. If per chance, the differential form is invariant by two substitutions, you can use one of the trigonometric functions of $2\theta$. If none works, the only solution is to set $t=\tan\frac\theta 2$.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to proceed:

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\tan^4\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{\tan^4\theta-1}{1-\tan^2\theta}d\theta+\int\frac{1}{1-\tan^2\theta}d\theta=-\int(\tan^2\theta+1)d\theta+\int\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}d\theta$

$=\displaystyle-\int\sec^2\theta \;d\theta+\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2\theta)}{\cos 2\theta}d\theta= -\tan\theta+\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\sec2\theta+\frac{1}{2}\right)d\theta$

$=\displaystyle-\tan\theta+\frac{1}{4}\ln\big|\sec2\theta+\tan2\theta\big|+\frac{1}{2}\theta+C$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: (This expands the hint of @Bernard... it was what I needed to make it work.)

Note that $\frac{1}{1-\tan^{2}(\theta)}=\frac{1+\tan^{2}(\theta)}{(1-\tan^{2}(\theta))(1+\tan^{2}(\theta))}=\frac{\sec^{2}(\theta)}{1-\tan^{4}(\theta)}$.

So using the suggested substitution $u=\tan(\theta)$ gives you

$$\int \frac{\tan^{4}\theta}{1-\tan^{2}\theta}d\theta= \int \frac{u^{4}}{1-u^4}du=\int -1 + \frac{1}{1-u^4}du.$$

Then, $(1-u^4)=(1-u)(1+u)(1+u^2)$ and can be finished with partial fractions.

Comment: wouldn't it be $\frac{u^4}{1-u^2}$ instead of power $4$?

Comment: @Foliar, No because you multiplied top and bottom by $1+u^2=1+\tan^{2}\theta=\sec^{2}\theta$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2(\theta)$. Rewrite $\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)$ as $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\sin^2(\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(2\theta)$. We know how to integrate $\sec(2\theta)$.

Comment: It took me a few moments to guess how you wanted to rewrite $\sin^2 \theta.$ OP might need a hint about that, too.

Comment: Yeah fair point - there's so much you could do. But having said that if there's a cos(2x) in the denominator...I guess when you 'see it' it seems so obvious (especially when the result immediately follows)!

Comment: very nice hint +1